# C# - MySql - Best way to convert data from MySqlDataReader to different models

Tags: c#, mysql

I have experience in working and fixing bugs with existing code bases that implement MySql code, but have to design a new program from scratch at my new job. I am not sure what is the best way to return data from `MySqlDataReader` to my custom models. Please advise!

Here's what I have,

**Folder structure:**

- Models (folder)

  1. Metadata.cs
  2. User.cs
- MySqlDb.cs

**Metadata.cs**: Reresents data from `metadata` table

```
public class Metadata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public bool IsLive { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs**: Represents data from `user` table

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**MySqlDb.cs**

```
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
public class MySqlDb
{
    public MySqlConnection Connection { get; set;} 
    public MySqlDb(string connectionString)
    {
        Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public List<Metadata> RunSelectQueryForMetadata(string query)
    {
        var rdr = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection).ExecuteReader();
        var metadata = new List<Metadata>();
        using (rdr)
        {
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                metadata.Add(
                    new Metadata {
                        Id = rdr["id"],
                        Title = rdr["title"],
                        Sku = rdr["sku"],
                        IsLive = rdr["islive"],
                    });
            } // while
        } // using 

        return metadata;

    } // public void RunSelectQuery(string query)

} // public class MySqlDb
```

If I try to get Users data, I am thinking of writing another method (`RunSelectQueryForUsers`). I would like to avoid writing different methods for different tables. I am not sure how to use one method for retrieving data from different tables with different data structures and typecast them to the Model I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use micro-orm such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) which is a simple object mapper built for .Net. Dapper extends the IDbConnection by providing useful extension methods to query your database.

Example of implementing dapper within your current menthod:

```
public List<Metadata> RunSelectQueryForMetadata(string query)
{
    var metadata = new List<Metadata>();
    try // implement proper error handling
    {
        Connection.Open();
        metadata = Connection.Query<Metadata>(query).ToList();
        Connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // error here
    }
    return metadata;
}
```

Some useful links:

- [Dapper Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)
- [Dapper Tutorial](http://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper)

Converting it to generic method: (*not tested right now*)

```
public List<T> RunSelectQuery<T>(string query)
{
    try // implement proper error handling
    {
        Connection.Open();
        metadata = Connection.Query<T>(query).ToList();
        Connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // error here
    }
    return metadata;
}
```

and use something like this below:

```
List<Metadata> myMetadata = RunSelectQuery<Metadata>(query);
```

Comment: Amazing!! I was breaking my head from this afternoon thinking on how to solve this :D

Comment: This is close, but one important thing still missing is a way for `RunSelectQuery<T>()` to handle query parameters. As it is, the method practically forces you to write horribly vulnerable sql statements. Additionally, rather than returning a List<T> and calling .ToList() in the method, you're usually better off working IEnumerable as much as possible instead, and leaving off the ToList() call as long as possible, until you really need it. Last of all, this needs a `finally` block or `using` block for the `Connection.Close()` call.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Open/Close connection, using/finally etc statements are there in my code, just didn't put them in question. I was just interested in using one generic method for most simple select queries! Now that I know of Dapper (thanks again John Woo), I will write my own code!!

Answer (score 1):

While not tailored to using MySql and straight up sql, the below code snippets provide a means to do what you're asking using generics. Could use some improvements though...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Data.General
{
    public abstract class DataObject
    {
        protected abstract void Initialize(IDataRecord dataRow);
        private static string _connectionString = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads a single data object from the results of a stored procedure.
        /// </summary>
        protected static T ReadObject<T>(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters, Type dataType)
        {
            DataObject returnItem = null;

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            using (SqlCommand command = BuildCommand(sqlConnection, procedureName, sqlParameters))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                //Execute the reader for the given stored proc and sql parameters
                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //If we get no records back we'll still return null
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        returnItem = (DataObject)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                        returnItem.Initialize(reader);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Return our DataObject
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(returnItem, dataType);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a collection of data objects from a stored procedure.
        /// </summary>
        protected static List<T> ReadObjects<T>(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
        {
            //Get cached data if it exists
            List<T> returnItems = new List<T>();
            T dataObject;

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            using (SqlCommand command = BuildCommand(sqlConnection, procedureName, sqlParameters, null))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                //Execute the reader for the given stored proc and sql parameters
                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //If we get no records back we'll still return null
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        dataObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                        (dataObject as DataObject).Initialize(reader);
                        returnItems.Add(dataObject);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Return the DataObjects
            return returnItems;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a SQL Command object that can be used to execute the given stored procedure.
        /// </summary>
        private static SqlCommand BuildCommand(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string procedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters, SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = null)
        {
            SqlParameter param;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnection);
            if (sqlTransaction != null)
            {
                cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
            }
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Add SQL Parameters (if any)
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in sqlParameters)
            {
                param = new SqlParameter(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.DbType);
                param.Value = parameter.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }

            return cmd;
        }

        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return _connectionString;
        }

        public static void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

    }
}

namespace Data.Library
{
    public class Metadata : General.DataObject
    {
        protected Data.Model.Metadata _metaData;

        public Data.Model.Metadata BaseModel
        {
            get { return _metaData; }
            set { _metaData = value; }
        }

        //Typically I have properties in here pointing to the Data.Model class

        protected override void Initialize(System.Data.IDataRecord dataRow)
        {
            _metaData = new Model.Metadata();

            _metaData.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["Id"].ToString());
            _metaData.Title = (dataRow["Title"].ToString());
            _metaData.Sku = (dataRow["Sku"].ToString());
            _metaData.IsLive = Convert.ToBoolean(dataRow["IsLive"].ToString());
        }

        public static Metadata ReadByID(int id)
        {
            return General.DataObject.ReadObject<Metadata>("dbo.s_MetadataGet", new[] { new SqlParameter("@ID", id) },
                typeof(Metadata));
        }

        public static Metadata[] ReadBySku(string sku)
        {
            List<Metadata> metaDatas = General.DataObject.ReadObjects<Metadata>("dbo.s_MetadataGetBySku", new[] { new SqlParameter("@Sku", sku) });
            return metaDatas.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

namespace Data.Model
{
    public class Metadata
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public bool IsLive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to call `sqlConnection.Close()` with a `using` block. Also, if you wait to open the connection until the command is ready, you can stack the connection and command using blocks directly on top of each other (my answer has an example of what this looks like). This saves you a level of indentation, which makes the code more readable, and slightly shortens the time for which you hold the connection open, which can be valuable on a busy system.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a pattern more like this:

```
public class MySqlDb
{
    //1. This should not be public!
    //     Keeping it private forces other code to go through your public methods, 
    //    rather than using the connection directly.
    //     Even better if the class knows how to read the string from a 
    //     config rile rather than accepting it via the constructor.
    //2. Don't save a connection object for re-use.
    //    ADO.Net has a connection pooling feature that works when you 
    //    create new objects for most queries
    private string ConnectionString { get; set;} 

    public MySqlDb(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    //1. Use IEnumerable instead of List 
    //    ...don't pull all of the results into memory at the same time until/unless you really have to.
    //2. Methods that accept query strings should also accept parameters. 
    //    Otherwise you are forced to build sql strings in insecure crazy-vulnerable ways
    public IEnumerable<Metadata> RunSelectQueryForMetadata(string query, IEnumerable<MySqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            if (parameters != null)
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            }

           cn.Open();
            using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                    yield return new Metadata {
                            Id = rdr["id"],
                            Title = rdr["title"],
                            Sku = rdr["sku"],
                            IsLive = rdr["islive"],
                        };
                }
                rdr.Close();
            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Ultimately, the ideal is for the `RunSelectQuery__()` method to be generic and **private**, and for public methods to *not* accept SQL statements. The goal is to force all SQL in your program to live in the `MySqlDb` class. Each query has a method that accepts specific typed inputs, and returns typed output. The *reason* you have that goal is to make it easy to manage your database access and easy to audit that all of your SQL code is safely using parameters (and *not vulnerable to sql injection attacks!* ). You want something like this:

```
//updated to remove the earlier explanatory comments 
//  and show example methods for isolating SQL from the rest of the application.
public class MySqlDb
{
    private string ConnectionString { get; set;} 

    private string ReadConnectionStringFromConfigFile()
    {
        //TODO
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }

    public MySqlDb()
    {
        ConnectionString = ReadConnectionStringFromConfigFile();
    }

    //This is now PRIVATE and generic, and allows for parameterized queries
    private IEnumerable<T> RunSelectQuery(string query, Func<IDataReader, T> translateRecord, IEnumerable<MySqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            if (parameters != null)
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            }

            cn.Open();
            using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                    yield return translateRecord(rdr);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            } 
        }
    }

    ////// Example methods showing how to use the generic method above
    // These methods are the only public part of your class

    public MetaData GetMetaDataById(int ID)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM MetatData WHERE ID= @ID";
        var parameters = new List<MySqlParameters> {
           new MySqlParameter() {
             ParameterName = "@ID",
             MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32,
             Value = ID
           }
        };

        return RunSelectQuery<MetaData>(sql, parameters, r =>
                        new Metadata {
                            Id = r["id"],
                            Title = r["title"],
                            Sku = r["sku"],
                            IsLive = r["islive"],
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<MetaData> GetAllMetaData()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM MetatData";

        return RunSelectQuery<MetaData>(sql, null, r =>
                        new Metadata {
                            Id = r["id"],
                            Title = r["title"],
                            Sku = r["sku"],
                            IsLive = r["islive"],
                        });
    }

    public User GetUserByID(int ID)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID= @ID";
        var parameters = new List<MySqlParameters> {
           new MySqlParameter() {
             ParameterName = "@ID",
             MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32,
             Value = ID
           }
        };

        return RunSelectQuery<User>(sql, parameters, r =>
                        new Metadata {
                            Id = r["id"],
                            UserName = r["UserName"],
                            Age = r["Age"],
                            Address = r["Address"],
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public User GetUserByUsername(string UserName)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username= @UserName";
        var parameters = new List<MySqlParameters> {
           new MySqlParameter() {
             ParameterName = "@UserName",
             MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
             Size = 20, //guessing at username lenght
             Value = UserName
           }
        };

        return RunSelectQuery<User>(sql, parameters, r =>
                        new Metadata {
                            Id = r["id"],
                            UserName = r["UserName"],
                            Age = r["Age"],
                            Address = r["Address"],
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> FindUsersByAge(int Age)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Age = @Age";
        var parameters = new List<MySqlParameters> {
           new MySqlParameter() {
             ParameterName = "@Age",
             MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32,
             Value = Age
           }
        };

        return RunSelectQuery<User>(sql, parameters, r =>
                        new Metadata {
                            Id = r["id"],
                            UserName = r["UserName"],
                            Age = r["Age"],
                            Address = r["Address"],
                        });
    }
}
```

In larger applications, you abstract this further into a separate project, with a private class for the lower-level methods that are private here, and a public class for each of the object types you use via that database. You might even go full-blown service-oriented architecture, where you get all your data via web service calls, and only the service layer talks directly to any database.

Of course, at this level you can also use a mirco-ORM like Dapper. Micro-ORMs will help you avoid re-writing the same mapping code over and over, and also help more with the INSERT/UPDATE side of data operations. Their goal is to take over as much of the boilerplate code for you as they can.

The advantage of a micro-ORM over a full ORM is it keeps you closer to the SQL. This is a *good thing*. Full-blown ORMs like Entity Framework or NHibernate effectively force you to learn a whole new language on top of the SQL, while mostly limiting you to basic SQL statements that often lose the advantages from the "relational" part of a relational database. Eventually, you often end up needing to understand and write complex raw SQL anyway to optimize performace. Micro-ORMs try to offer a happy-medium... taking away as much of the boiler plate code needed to talk to a database as they can, while still leaving you to write your own SQL.

Comment: But is this not beating the purpose? Your method loop can be used only for `Metadata` class, you'll have to write another method to read another table's data?

Comment: You ideally want a separate method for individual queries that only accept typed parameter info and return only typed results. Will update the answer in a moment w/ more info.